# Finding value of $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} e^{x^2} dx dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, improper-integrals, exponential-sum

I have an integral,

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} e^{x^2} dx dy$$

I tried to apply integration by parts on the inner integral with respect to $x$ but it didn't seem to progress. Does anyone have a better approach?

Comment: Change the order of integration.

Comment: Is it permitted? I didn't do it because the integral bound is $y$ which is dependent.

Comment: @SahilSilare Not just permitted, but virtually required. The *point* of these questions in a typical calc textbook is to illustrate the utility of changing the order of integration -- but of course you need to change the limits *correctly*. To do that, it helps to sketch the domain that you are integrating over.

Comment: You can change the order, but in this case not simply by swapping the two integrals as is (because of the dependence of a bound on a variable, as you say). To switch the order correctly here, it would be good to draw a diagram of the region of integration, as others have mentioned.

Comment: I thought we could say that:
$$\int_0^1\int_y^1e^{x^2}dxdy=\int_0^1\text{erf}(1)-\text{erf}(y)dy=\left[y\text{erf}(1)-y\text{erf}(y)-\frac{e^{-y^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right]_0^1=\left[-\frac{e^{-y^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right]_0^1=\frac{1-e^{-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
Although this appears to be wrong :(

Comment: @HenryLee But why so?

Comment: Depending on how we define erf it is known to be the integral of $e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that, since the region of integration is the triangle whose vertices ae $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$, your integral is equal to$$\int_0^1\int_0^xe^{x^2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1xe^{x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Can you explain how did you changed the bounds?

Comment: Try sketching the region of integration in the $xy$-plane (It should be a right angled triangle). It should then be clear.

Comment: @SahilSilare I've edited my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for explaining!